# Raman scattering collection geometry

Tags: spectroscopy, vibrations, raman-spectroscopy

I believe that most Raman spectroscopy measurements are carried out with the collection optics being at either 180$^{\circ}$(back-scattering) or 90$^{\circ}$ from the excitation source. Are there any particular reason for these geometries? I am aware angle-resolved Raman spectroscopy is also a technique people use (and that there is an angle dependence), so is there anything special with these two angles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this question from the perspective of the Raman scattering experimentalist with the condensed matter background.

These are, indeed, most popular geometries with backscattering one being truly the dominating one, at least in the the field of micro-Raman scattering.
The advantage of the backscattering one that you can use single objective for both excitation light and inelastically scattered one, which is cost-efficient.
In particular, for this geometry, you can use objectives with very high numerical aperture (you want to collect as much scattered light as possible) with very low working distance (less than a millimeter), which simply does not allow to put a second objective. Another advantage is the possibility to work with non-transparent or very thin (e.g. 2D flakes) samples and to perform mapping (2D scan) measurements.
The disadvantage is that most of the excitation light goes back (just by specular reflection) and you have to take care of it somehow, which is not much of a problem nowadays, but could be costly, with triple-grating spectrometers, notch or volume-Bragg filters.

The 90$^∘$ geometry mostly comes from the good old days, when the effective ways to take care of the excitation light (which is a few orders of magnitude more intense and easily overshadow Raman scattering signal) were limited.
So they focus excitation light into the transparent sample and collected scattered light by 90$^∘$.
This way most of the excitation light just pass the sample and you can pass inelastically scattered light more-or-less directly to spectrometer.
The schemes and figures for such early experiments in 90$^∘$ [1].

Another aspect is determination of the symmetry of the excitations via polarized Raman scattering.
For both these geometries it is possible to achieve a condition when observed excitations are completely disappear or have maximum intensity for specific combination of polarizations of the incoming and scattered light according to its selection rules.
Usually it is tabulated for all point groups or easily calculated.
For arbitrary-angle geometry it is much harder to achieve.

[1] [Scattering of Light by One- and Two-Magnon Excitations](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.166.514), P. A. Fleury and R. Loudon, Phys. Rev. 166, 514 (1968).